# How to set/change a checkbox checked atribute in html code

Tags: html, checkbox, set

I have an input page where users enters the attending hours for a business, it displays each day schedule and the user can enter the open and close time, also have a little checkbox saying it is 24 hours open, if the business wil be open 24 hours the whole week, i want to avoid the user from clicking 7 checkboxes(one for each day) instead, i have a radio button which says "24 hours" and i want that when a user clicks on it it will check the 24 hour checkbox for all the 7 days automaticaly. i just don't know how to check/uncheck a checkbox once it has been created or displayed

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Javascript to edit the other radio buttons. You can add an onclick to the 24 hour radio to call a function such as selectall():

```
function selectall(){
mondayradio = document.getElementById("theid");
mondayradio.checked = true;
}
```

You would just copy the center two lines for each radio button you want to check, and change their ids to match.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7vwkwe0/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" />24 Hours<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1">Sunday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="2">Monday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="3">Tuesday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="4">Wednesday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="5">Thursday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="6">Friday<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="7">Saturday<br/>
```

**JS**

```
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
```

In the fiddle that i've specified, when the first check box, ie 24 Hours is checked, all the other checkboxes will automatically gets checked.

And, if you want to use Radio Button instead of checkbox, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7vwkwe0/1/)